# Compare strings in List 1 with values in List 2, and export to new location

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, grep

I'm trying to compare 2 .csv files against each other - the first looks like this (list1.csv):

```
london,
clapham,
brighton,
oxford,
elephant and castle,
```

This is effectively a list of locations, that has a total length of over 20,000  rows (locations)

The sheet that I am comparing this against looks like this (but has a lot of random words in)(list2.csv):

```
iron service,
ironing london,
laundry chelmsford,
dry cleaners elephant and castle,
laundry in oxford,
```

The output that I am aiming for would be:

```
ironing london,
laundry chelmsford,
dry cleaners elephant and castle,
laundry in oxford,
```

I am trying to use grep to accomplish this, but the data that i get has a number of unrelated words (that are in my second list). I am effectively trying to compare 'strings' in list1.csv - that can contain spaces - with data in the list2.csv. If the string shows up anywhere in a line in list 2, I want that line exported to a new location "list3"

grep that I am using:

```
grep -F list1.csv list2.csv > list3.csv
```

from what i can see from the output, the 'strings' are not being treated as such from list1.csv, and instead are being treated as single words - so if a string contains 2 words, it will extract a line that has either of those words.

Comment: why the line `laundry chelmsford` should be in the result? A typo? elaborate your question

Comment: sorry - 'chelmsford' also appears within the list1.csv - it is a list of over 20,000 locations within the UK, with some locations being 2 or 3 words long e.g. "crouch end" or "avon upon thames" - am trying to find a way to get grep to search for the whole string in a cell (or any alternatives)

Comment: *updated the question -  grep -F list1.csv list2.csv > list3.csv

Comment: you mention your file is csv, but there are no `,` in your sample data.. if there is some field based matching to be done, having field separator shown in sample would help

Comment: The .csv files are single column files, hence why no seperator shown - have updated the question with seperators

Comment: if it is single column, then no need to show separators.. it was just a doubt I had...

Comment: would text in list2 having "'" in, or "-" affect this? Or any other special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Simple **`grep`** approach:

```
grep -Ff list1.csv list2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this, but am still getting unrelated words in the output - for example 'wash and fold' is appearing - but this is not in List1 - only in list2 - can you explain why this may be happening?

Comment: could this maybe be to do with any words within list1 that also have 'and' in?